# Trouble with nested while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, square

Please help me, Im using codeblocks 16 and I dont know why this code doesnt print a square, is just a square!
Another thing is how can I improve this code?
Im still learning please dont be mad at me
thanks so much for you time

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    char a = 'a', d = ' ';
    int b = 0, c = 0;

    while (c < 5) {
        cout << a;
        c = c + 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
    c = 0;
    while (c < 3) {
        cout << a;
        while (b < 3) {
            cout << d;
            b = b + 1;
        }
        cout << a << endl;
        c = c + 1;
    }
    c = 0;
    while (c < 5) {
        cout << a;
        c = c + 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once `b` hits 3, that `while` loop can never run again. Use `for` loops instead of `while` loops for cases like this.

Comment: Step through with a debugger and watch your variables while doing so

Comment: You need to reset `b` to `0` at the start/end of each of the outer loop iterations as above.

Comment: You *can* use a `while` inside a `while`, and you *have*. Don't write meaningless titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to reinitialize `b` to `0`.

Using `for` would be easier to read:

```
for(int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
    cout << a;
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; ++b) {
        cout << d;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is so embarrassing...

Comment: In the future, add as much logging as you need to until you can figure it out. For example, before `while (b < 3) {` you could have temporarily added a line like `cout << "About to enter b while loop, b=" << b << endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you do not reset the value of `b` every time you loop through your outer loop.  Thus, on the second row of the square (the first row with spaces), it works just fine.  However, on the third row, as you get to the inner while loop, `b` still equals 3 from the previous pass through that loop.

If I may also make a suggestion at the same time, name your variables meaningfully, and the errors will become more obvious.  I would recommend using variables `row` and `column` rather than `b` and `c`.  Sometimes all you need is slightly clearer variable names, and the bug stands out.

Comment: I appreciate your time ,thank you sir, I will